# Sending reminder for LOR and asking them to do it early?

Tags: masters, etiquette, recommendation-letter

I'm applying for the Spring Semester for 5 Master's programs, with deadlines ranging from Oct 15th to Dec 10th. I sent all the information to my 2 Professors who are writing the letters. I guess I was naive in thinking they would write the letter pretty fast, now I'm freaking out they might wait until the deadlines of December. (It's been two weeks.) That wouldn't give me much time to choose a program, and move by classes that start in the spring semester!

All the programs say they will make an offer about a week or two after reviewing my application, which they won't start until AFTER they get my letters. I really want my Professors to write the letters ASAP. How can I tell them I'd like them to submit them before the deadline? Is that OK?

Answer (score 3):

You sent "all the information" - including deadlines?  You can expect that they will submit by the deadlines that you told them, but not necessarily before.

If you need the letters earlier than you originally said, you'll just have to ask them - no way around it, and the sooner the better.  If your new deadline is still at least a few weeks away, it shouldn't be too much of an inconvenience for the professors.  If you tell them "You know that letter I asked you to submit in December?  I actually need it tomorrow," they will very likely get annoyed, and may not be able to have it ready in time.